# Text with RegEx Validator not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, validation

I have an issue with the following text display:

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="Password_RegularExpValidate" runat="server" 
     Text="TEST!" 
     Display="Dynamic" 
     BorderStyle="None" 
     ControlToValidate="txtNewPass" 
     ValidationExpression="(?=^.{8,255}$)((?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])|(?=.*\d)(?=.*[^A-Za-z0-9])(?=.*[a-z])|(?=.*[^A-Za-z0-9])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])|(?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[^A-Za-z0-9]))^.*" 
     meta:resourcekey="Password_RegularExpValidateResource1" /></td>
```

The pattern by itself is:

```
(?=^.{8,255}$)((?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])|(?=.*\d)(?=.*[^A-Za-z0-9])(?=.*[a-z])|(?=.*[^A-Za-z0-9])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])|(?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[^A-Za-z0-9]))^.*
```

The text initially had some stuff in it as the ValidationExpression was different.  I've changed the regex expression and that works, but when I write something in Text= it doesn't update on the page.  I've restarted IIS, cleard the IE chache...   everything I could think of.  The old text keeps appearings (ie. "TEST!" doesn't show up when the validation fails as it should).

Any help would be appreciated.

Edit:

The code for txtnewpass:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtNewPass" runat="server" 
     TextMode="Password" 
     MaxLength="256" 
     meta:resourcekey="txtNewPassResource1"></asp:TextBox>
```

Also, it's worth noting that I can remove an entire table from a page that it disappears when I reload the page.  But when I change text values from controls or anything that runat="server" and the page doesn't seem to update with the text....

And the code behind doesn't edit the field that displays, the validator validates the text in the textbox and uses that value later.

Edit 2: Same thing happening with -

```
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" 
     Text="Change Password!!!!!" 
     meta:resourcekey="Label1Resource1"></asp:Label></td>
```

I've added the exclamation marks (!!!!!) and that's not showing up when I refresh the page either.....

Edit 3: As I've noted in one of the comments, if I delete a table from the page and reload the page, that table disappears, so I know the page is reloading properly.  The runat="Server" property, does that work a certain way where it caches text or something?  I'm out of ideas....

Comment: Also, I tried a brief test to change another part of the page:

    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Change Password!!!!!" meta:resourcekey="Label1Resource1"></asp:Label></td>

I added the multiple exclamation marks and that's not updating on the page either!!

Comment: Please show more complete code, such as the definition of the control being validated (txtNewPass) and any code-behind which manipulates either.  (And edit to add more info, don't add comments with code in them, they don't format pretty)

Comment: Do you have a validation group on your submit button? If so the validator control does not so it will not be validated.  Also if your submit button is not set to causes validation then it also will not work.

Comment: Have you tried cleaning the solution?

Comment: Also have you tested the regex anywhere else?  I am not a regex wiz but it looks like it will always pass to me.

Comment: I don't have the original solution, it's not my original code.  Also see edit as I don't think it's to do with the validator as the same thing happens to a label....

Comment: See edit 2, it's happening with a label on the page as well.  Although if I remove html code (like a table) and refresh, the entire table does disappear...  so certain things on the page update....

Comment: Do you have the markup and the code-behind for the page that is showing this problem?  Not the entire solution, just the page with the validator and other issues.

Comment: If you think the regex pattern could be the problem, you should separate it out by itself and try to format it to be more readable. Parsing all that in my head made my brain hurt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Like Kirill said, use ErrorMessage instead of Text.
2. But the main problem is, I think, your localization, which is handled through the meta:resourcekey tag and resources. 
   Here is a good explanation:
   [ASP.NET meta:resourcekey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/755384/asp-net-metaresourcekey/755430#755430)

If you set automatically or manually the resource localization file and change something afterwards, for example a Label Text property, then you need to do it in the resource file too. Because there should be your initial value, which is loaded at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

- Try to use RegularExpressionValidator.ErrorMessage instead of Text.
- Try restarting VS. Sometimes incredible bugs disappear after that.
- Try removing and regenerating your ..aspx.designer.cs file (to
  regenerate right click the aspx/ascx file and choose "convert to web
  application").
- Agree with others, you should indeed check your resource file.

Comment: See edit 2, it's happening with a label on the page as well...  so maybe with anything that has runat="server"??

Comment: I tried his code as pasted above, and it worked just fine.  From his edits above, I think it's something more global, not just his validator(s).

Comment: I think it is as well Tim, I've tried at it for 40 minutes before posting, can't figure it out :(

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of possibilities for the source of the problem, and there's not really enough info to tell which one it is. It sounds to me like one of these:

1) An external issue with your application or page (perhaps your ViewState isn't being set up properly, or the validation is getting called before PostBack).

2) You should be using `RegularExpressionValidator.ErrorMessage` instead of `Text`, as Kirill suggested. You said that you had changed that, but I wonder if you've reloaded the page (you could try rebuilding the app or something if it's getting cached somehow).

3) Your regex might not be doing what you think it is. The pattern is extremely long, and it seems strangely written. Adding some whitespace, we find that it looks like this:

```
(?=^.{8,255}$)
(
    (?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])
    |
    (?=.*\d)(?=.*[^A-Za-z0-9])(?=.*[a-z])
    |
    (?=.*[^A-Za-z0-9])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])
    |
    (?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[^A-Za-z0-9])
)^.*
```

Which simplifies down to something like:

```
^(
     (?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[\W_])(?=.*[a-z\d])
     |
     (?=.*[a-z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*([A-Z\W_]))
  ).{8,255}$
```

Is this what you intended? I see where you're going with the password rules, but it may be easier to just simplify them and require one capital, one lowercase, one number, and one special character. You could also try to get validation working with a simpler regex pattern, and then add complexity once everything else is working.

Comment: I was trying to represent the Microsoft password rules, in fact the above regex I found and tested, it wasn't an original from me.

Comment: @ibm1 - Fair enough; either way, I would test your application with a shorter regex until you're sure that the pattern isn't the problem. And simplifying as above should make the pattern easier to debug in the future.