# Meta property in drop down controls?

Tags: asp.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [ASP.NET meta:resourcekey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/755384/asp-net-metaresourcekey)

In asp.net. what is the use of using "meta:resoucekey" in dropdownlist controls.

```
  <asp:ComboBox ID="ddlAccounts" runat="server" Width="130px" MaxLength="0" 
        meta:resourcekey="ddlAccountsResource1" style="display: inline;" 
        AutoCompleteMode="SuggestAppend" ItemInsertLocation="OrdinalText">
    </asp:ComboBox>
```

can any one explain me.

Comment: Check this SO answer for some details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/755384/asp-net-metaresourcekey

Answer (score 0):

I use meta:resourcekey="myString" with resource (xml) files to enable multi-language support.  You can have many resource files (one for each language), each with the same keys.  Key values vary depending on the language.  Your aspx file will read from the relevant resource file based on the page locale.

For example, I use a resource file Default.aspx.resx for English language resources (strings) and Default.aspx.fr-FR.resx for French language resources.

I then add the following code to each .aspx page.  There may be a neater way but this works well for me.

```
protected override void InitializeCulture()
{
    if (Request.QueryString["lang"] == "fr")
    {
        base.InitializeCulture();
        System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("fr-FR");
        System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("fr-FR");
    }
    else
    {
        base.InitializeCulture();
        System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("en-GB");
        System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-GB");
    }
}
```

Comment: Oops, just realised your question was about dropdown lists, nevertheless the answer above may assist others so I'll leave it in place.